# How to verify native app link and going back to the app

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I am using appium for mobile automation for testing iOS and Android native app. 
Here is the use case
e.g. 
launch whatsapp
Tap on Setting
Tap on Help
Tap on Terms & Privacy Policy

How I can make sure that it navigate to browser and how I can came back to the app.

Comment: Are you talking about browser or native apps ? What steps have you done ?

Comment: 1. Launch the Whatsapp 
2. Tap on Settings 
3. Tap on Help 
4. Tap on Terms and Privacy Policy. 
This will open external browser and navigate to https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/?lg=en&lc=US&eea=0.

How do I do automate in appium for iOS and Android.

Comment: I mean in my native app few menu option navigating to browser. So how I can make sure it's navigated to browser with correct link. e.g. I gave above this comment,

Comment: Please paste your current code . @Hari

Refer to http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/api/ for documentation.

Comment: have you found the solution @Hari